# Elasticsearch: scroll search with _doc sort - terminated_early flag

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using scroll search, ES 6.8, transport client. When sorting by a column, everything is ok. But when sorting using a _doc field (transport client generates request {"sort":[{"_doc":{"order":"asc"}}]}), terminated_early flag is returned along the response.

Is this normal? I probably do not understand the flag, I thought that it means that the response is not complete. But when I continue scrolling by ignoring the terminated_early flag, it seems that I get the same result as when sorting by a column (same documents, different order). Btw I query an alias, not an index.